# Join 2 arrays of objects based on grouping properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, object, group-by

With the following JSON API response:

```
{
   "default" : [
      {"val_a" : 5 , "val_b": 10, "key_a":"A", "key_b":"X"},
      {"val_a" : 15 , "val_b": 11, "key_a":"A", "key_b":"Y"},
      {"val_a" : 6 , "val_b": 12, "key_a":"B", "key_b":"Z"}
   ],
   "alt" : [
      {"val_a" : 15 , "val_b": 11, "key_a":"A", "key_b":"Y"},
      {"val_a" : 9 , "val_b": 10, "key_a":"A", "key_b":"X"}
   ]
}
```

I'm trying to write a merging function that will give the following results:

```
[
 {"alt_val_a":9, "alt_val_b":10 ,"val_a" : 5 , "val_b": 10, "key_a":"A", "key_b":"X"},
 {"alt_val_a":15, "alt_val_b":11 ,"val_a" : 15 , "val_b": 11, "key_a":"A", "key_b":"Y"},
 {"val_a" : 6 , "val_b": 12, "key_a":"B", "key_b":"Z"}
]
```

**Explanation**:
The results are merged based on 2 properties,"key_a" **and** "key_b" that produce a unique entry combination. The "alt" prefix is added to the other properties.

**EDIT:** The grouping keys (key_b , key_a) in the example above are **dynamically changing based on the request to the api**, so another API response could have another grouping key involved, for example key_c, therefore the function should be generic enough to accept the grouping keys as an array.

**Edit 2** Just to make it clear, val_a and val_b are just an example of a specific response. On another response val_c could be present or val_a could be missing.

I'm thinking of a function that accepts the original JSON and an array of group by keys
like so:

```
function transformResults(results,groupings){
   //...
}
```

Usage:

```
transformResults(originalJSON,["key_a","key_b"]);
```

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: do you really want to change the property names for new added values in the same group?

Comment: Yes, since the alt part of the response represent different values, they just happen to have the save key

Answer (score 0):

You could use a hash table for the same group.

This proposal mutates the original object.

```js
function transformResults(object, keys) {
    var getValues = function (o) { return function (k) { return o[k]; }; },
        hash = Object.create(null),
        result = object.default.map(function (o) {
            var key = keys.map(getValues(o)).join('|');
            return hash[key] = o;
        });

    object.alt.forEach(function (o) {
        var key = keys.map(getValues(o)).join('|');
        if (!hash[key]) {
            result.push(hash[key] = {});
            keys.forEach(function (k) {
                hash[key][k] = o[k];
            });
        }
        Object.keys(o).forEach(function (k) {
            if (keys.indexOf(k) === -1) {
                return;
            }
            hash[key]['alt_' + k] = o[k];
        });
    });
    return result;
}

var object = { default: [{ val_a: 5, val_b: 10, key_a: "A", key_b: "X" }, { val_a: 15, val_b: 11, key_a: "A", key_b: "Y" }, { val_a: 6, val_b: 12, key_a: "B", key_b: "Z" }], alt: [{ val_a: 15, val_b: 11, key_a: "A", key_b: "Y" }, { val_a: 9, val_b: 10, key_a: "A", key_b: "X" }, { val_a: 9, val_b: 10, key_a: "C", key_b: "X" }] };

console.log(transformResults(object, ["key_a", "key_b"]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Almost, but if the alt array contains a unique combination that does not exists in the default array it will be left out, for example add `{"val_a" : 9 , "val_b": 10, "key_a":"C", "key_b":"X"}` to the alt array it should appear in the following results as `{"alt_val_a" : 9 , "alt_val_b": 10, "key_a":"C", "key_b":"X"}`

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the original results and create a new Object based on the group keys like so:

```
{ AX: 
   { val_a: 5,
     val_b: 10,
     key_a: 'A',
     key_b: 'X',
     alt_val_a: 9,
     alt_val_b: 10 },
  AY: 
   { val_a: 15,
     val_b: 11,
     key_a: 'A',
     key_b: 'Y',
     alt_val_a: 15,
     alt_val_b: 11 },
  BZ: { val_a: 6, val_b: 12, key_a: 'B', key_b: 'Z' } }
```

Then map the keys to the final array.
Here is my generic version:

```js
function transformResults(results, groupings) {
  let reducedResults = Object.keys(results).reduce((modified, originalKey) => {
    //iterating over the original results
    results[originalKey].forEach((row) => {
      //creating a dynamic key based on the grouping key values
      let groupKey = groupings.reduce((resultKey, keyVal) => {
        resultKey = resultKey + row[keyVal];
        return resultKey;
      }, "");

      //iterating over each row values
      Object.keys(row).forEach((rowKey) => {
        //determine if a prefix should be added to the original row key
        let finalKey = (originalKey === 'default' || groupings.indexOf(rowKey) !== -1) ? rowKey : originalKey + "_" + rowKey;
        //creating a modified object where the key is the unique group value
        modified[groupKey] = modified[groupKey] || {};
        modified[groupKey][finalKey] = row[rowKey];
      });
    });
    return modified;
  }, {});

  //mapping the object results and modifying the results to an array
  return Object.keys(reducedResults).map((gKey) => {
    return reducedResults[gKey];
  });
}

let data = {
  "default": [
    {"val_a": 5, "val_b": 10, "key_a": "A", "key_b": "X"},
    {"val_a": 15, "val_b": 11, "key_a": "A", "key_b": "Y"},
    {"val_a": 6, "val_b": 12, "key_a": "B", "key_b": "Z"}
  ],
  "alt": [
    {"val_a": 15, "val_b": 11, "key_a": "A", "key_b": "Y"},
    {"val_a": 9, "val_b": 10, "key_a": "A", "key_b": "X"}
  ]
};

console.log(transformResults(data, ["key_a", "key_b"]));
```

Comment: Super, that is what I was looking for!